# Melhorar a forma de desativar textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho este botão para inserir um novo registo:

```
<button type="button" name="add6" id="add6" class="btn btn-primary disable" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal6" data-whatever="@getbootstrap" style="font-size: 12px;">Passagem de Turno</button>
```

E este botão para fazer update em outra página mas que utiliza o mesmo formulário do botão anterior:

```
<button type="button" name="edit6" data-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModal6" id="'.$row6["Id6"].'" class="btn btn-primary edit_data6 disable1" >Editar</button>
```

os input textarea dque existem dentro do form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <h6><label for="Observacao-name" class="col-form-label">Tarefa Pendente</label></h6>
  <textarea type="text" id="Observacao6" name="Observacao6" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="disabled form-group">
 <h6><label for="Observacao-name" class="col-form-label">Conclusão</label></h6>
 <textarea type="text" id="Conclusao" name="Conclusao" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

javascript para o primeiro botão:

```
$(".disable").click(function (){
        // desabilitando o campo 
    $('#Conclusao').attr("disabled", true);
    // mudando a cor do campo
    $('#Conclusao').css("background-color", "#cccccc"); 
});
```

e na página do segundo botão também coloco para o outro textarea:

```
$(".disable1").click(function (){
  // desabilitando o campo 
  $('#Observacao6').attr("disabled", true);
  // mudando a cor do campo
   $('#Observacao6').css("background-color", "#cccccc"); 
});
```

Quando faço para inserir funciona corretamente como mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando faço o update bloquea os dois textarea, mas só devia bloquear o primeiro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Chamo a página (que é a select16), por que a `conexao16` só tem o `php` para `insert` e fazer `update` onde tem o botão de editar e o gatilho `disable1` da seguinte forma:**

```
$(".disable").click(function (){
        // desabilitando o campo 
    $('#Conclusao').attr("disabled", true);
    // mudando a cor do campo
    $('#Conclusao').css("background-color", "#cccccc"); 
});

$('#add6').click(function(){  
           $('#insert6').val("Gravar");  
           $('#insert_form6')[0].reset();  
      });

    $('#insert_form6').on("submit", function(event){  
           event.preventDefault(); 
           if($('#Colaborador6').val() == "")  
           {  
                alert("Colaborador é necessário");  
           }               
           else  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:".conexao26",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#insert_form6').serialize()
                     ,  
                     beforeSend:function(){  

                          $('#insert6').val("Inserting");  
                     },

                     success:function(data){                     

                          $('#insert_form6')[0].reset();  
                          $('#exampleModal6').modal('hide'); 
                          $('#employee_table6').html(data);                       
                          location.reload("exampleModal6");                       
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });

       $(document).on('click', '.view_data6', function(){  
           var employee_id6 = $(this).attr("Id");  
           if(employee_id6 != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"./select16",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{employee_id6:employee_id6},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#employee_detail6').html(data);  
                          $('#dataModal6').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           }            
      });
```

Mas o problema só surge se usar nos dois botões, se usar só no botão de editar já funciona correctamente, mas se usar nos dois já não funciona.

**html:**

```
<form method="post" id="insert_form6">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <h6><label for="Data-name" class="col-form-label">Data</label></h6>
            <h6><input type="date" name="data6" id="data6" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"></h6>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <h6><label for="Colaborador-text" class="col-form-label">Colaborador</label></h6>
            <h6><select style="width:150px" name="Colaborador6" id="Colaborador6" required>

<option></option>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT Funcionario FROM centrodb.InfoLuvas WHERE Ativo = '1' AND Funcao = 'Limpeza' AND Valencia = 'LAR'";
$qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
  echo '<option value="'.$ln['Funcionario'].'">'.$ln['Funcionario'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select></h6>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
         </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <h6><label for="Observacao-name" class="col-form-label">Tarefa Pendente</label></h6>
            <textarea type="text" id="Observacao6" name="Observacao6" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
          <h6><label for="Observacao-name" class="col-form-label">Estado</label></h6> 
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>
          <h6><input type="radio" id="Estado" name="Estado" value="Pendente"> Pendente &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" id="Estado" name="Estado" value="Concluído"> Concluído</h6> 
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
         </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="disabled form-group">
            <h6><label for="Observacao-name" class="col-form-label">Conclusão</label></h6>
            <textarea type="text" id="Conclusao" name="Conclusao" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
          <div class="form-group">
          <h6><input type="hidden" name="Nome6" id="Nome6" value="Ana Ribeiro" readonly="true"></h6>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
          <div class="form-group">
          <h6><input type="hidden" name="NomeConc" id="NomeConc" value="Ana Ribeiro" readonly="true"></h6>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="employee_id6" id="employee_id6" />
        <input type="submit" name="insert6" id="insert6" value="Registo" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success" /> 
      </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Você colocou o gatilho no mesmo botão: `$(".disable").click(function (){`. O botão de editar tá com classe `.disable1`. Seria isso?!

Comment: Pode explicar melhor como está a estrutura de arquivos? Sua resposta depende um pouco de onde você está chamando cada função javascript. Por exemplo: você poderia mostrar que tal página contendo conteúdo X chama tal arquivo contendo conteúdo Y. Talvez o LipESprY tenha respondido!!

Comment: @LipESprY o problema não é esse, mesmo corrigindo esse problema acontece o mesmo.

Comment: Confesso que estou com um pouco de dificuldade de entender seus códigos. Talvez seja a síndrome de "antes de almoçar". Considere facilitar nos detalhes e volto depois do almoço pra tentar te ajudar! ;D

Comment: @Cedric S. editei a pergunta com o `ajax` que chama a página que tem o gatilho `disable1`

Comment: você colocou somente alguns trechos do código `html`, e nesses trechos não aparecem os botoes citados. Entretanto um teste que você pode fazer e trocar seus selectors para algo um pouco mais especifico como `$('button.disable').click(...)` e `$('button.disable1').click(...)` digo isso porque você pode esta usando essa classe `.disable` em outros elementos.

Comment: @Icaro Martins fiz o teste como indicou acima mas o resultado é o mesmo, quando clico no botão editar ficam os dois bloqueados

Comment: Olha esse exemplo o botão `<button type="button" name="add6" id="add6" class="btn btn-primary disable" ....>` esta recebendo 2 eventos de `click`  esse `$(".disable").click(...)` e esse `$('#add6').click(...)`, vale apena você verificar se isso esta correto e se isso se repete com outros eventos. Se você adicionar o `html` do seu código pode ser que fique mais fácil para a comunidade identificar o problema - [mcve]. =D

Comment: @Icaro Martins adicionei o html na pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para desativar e ativar `textarea` usei a função `prop()` onde num botão ativo e no outro desativo o `textarea`. Anexei o manipulador de eventos usando a função `click` que é chamada depois da página carregada. Peguei o campo de texto usando o selector de `ID` e depois chamei o `prop("disabled", false ou true")` para desativar ou ativar.

Na página onde pretendo ativar o `textarea id=Observacao6"` e desativar o `textarea id="Conclusao"` coloquei na funçao `click` do botão o seguinte código:

```
$("#Observacao6").prop("disabled", false);
$("#Conclusao").prop("disabled", true);
```

código completo:

```
$('#add6').click(function(){  
$("#Observacao6").prop("disabled", false);
$("#Conclusao").prop("disabled", true);
$('#insert6').val("Gravar");  
$('#insert_form6')[0].reset();  
});
```

Na página onde pretendo desativar o `textarea id=Observacao6"` e ativar o `textarea id="Conclusao"` coloquei na funçao `click` do botão o seguinte código:

```
$("#Observacao6").prop("disabled", true);
$("#Conclusao").prop("disabled", false);
```

Código completo:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data6', function(){  
           var employee_id6 = $(this).attr("Id");
           var lis = $("#Estado").val();

           $.ajax({  
                url:"./fetch26",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id6:employee_id6},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){
                  var teste = data.Estado;
                     $('#data6').val(data.data6);
                     $('#Colaborador6').val(data.Colaborador6); 
                     $('#Observacao6').val(data.Observacao6);
                     $("#Observacao6").prop("disabled", true);
                     if(lis == data.Estado){
                     $('#Estado').prop('checked' , true);
                     }else{ 
                     $('#Estado1').prop('checked' ,true);
                     } 
                     $("#Conclusao").prop("disabled", false);
                     $('#Conclusao').val(data.Conclusao);
                     $('#employee_id6').val(data.Id6);
                     $('#insert6').val("Gravar");                    
                     $('#exampleModal6').modal('show'); 

                }  
           });  
      });
```

> Nota: se estiver a executar no jquery 1.5 ou versão inferior, basta
>   substituir o `prop()` por `attr()` e deve funcionar.